# To get best accuracy from Testing dataset

Tags: python, machine-learning, random-forest

I am using Random forest classifier to classify data into 4 labels. There are a total of 20 features on which the model is being trained. I am observing an accuracy of around 45-47 % when Testing dataset is used. Although on prediction of Training dataset I'm getting an accuracy of 100%. Also I'm using the best parameters extracted using Grid Search approach. Can anyone explain why such kind of biasing between training and testing prediction. How can I enhance the scenario?

PS: I'm new to Machine Learning

Comment: First of all this is not the right platform for your question. Ask it in `StackExchange`. The possible reason is you are overfitting the model.

Comment: If you have trouble understanding why your model would perform better on the set it trained (in other words 'learned') from than the one it has never seen before, you may want to do some basic machine learning related reading. In the process of training you "fit" your model to best represent the training data. Ideally, this data is chosen carefully so it will generalize to any unknown data set. Most models will score (near) perfectly on their training sets, since that's the input they try to generalize from.

Answer (score 0):

There might be many Reasons
1)one might be, model is over fitting. you can try doing hyper parameter optimization to find the optimal value where your model performs better.
2) Since you are using accuracy as a performance parameter, You can check whether data set is balanced or not. If you are using imbalanced data set,you can use ROC,AUC Characteristics.